# Why is python stoping at the line Webdriver.Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, encryption, pycharm, tor

My code seems to stop at the line "driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)".
Im trying to use selenium with the tor browser. I need it to first connect to the servers though.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import time

# Set the path to the Tor browser binary
tor_binary_path = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe'

# Create a Firefox options object
options = Options()

# Configure the profile settings
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)

# Specify the binary path
options.binary_location = tor_binary_path

# Create a Firefox service with the Tor browser binary path
service = Service(tor_binary_path)

# Create a Firefox webdriver with the Tor browser options and service
print("webdrive")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

# Wait for Tor to connect to its servers
print("wait")
time.sleep(1)  # Adjust the sleep duration as needed

# Navigate to google.com
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print("Done")
```

Ive tried erasing what was inside the ()
for ex:"driver = webdriver.Firefox()"
And then tor would prompt me to my site but it wouldnt connect to its servers.
How do I get it to connect to its servers and be able to use selenium.